# Facebook Timeline Scroll Event that loads more content

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to isolate the Facebook JS/Ajax event that fires when more content is loaded.
This is - when you've been on the page for a certain amount of time and new posts show up. Or when you scroll to the bottom of the page and more posts are loaded.

I've tried going through every aspect of Chrome's developer tools to pinpoint that event but I'm just not getting anywhere. Facebook is very tricky in the way it names everything so that it's not human friendly.

The closest I'm getting is finding an event listener on line 20 of a file called PBlKb9_thnY.js (which may be named dynamically so be different for others), but I can't get any further than this.

Basically I want to identify the function that loads more content and then attach my own Javascript code to the end of it through an extension.

Comment: Try looking at the source of some scripts for [infinite scrolling](https://www.google.ca/search?q=infinite+scroll).

Comment: You misunderstood the question. I'm not asking how to infinite-scroll, I'm asking what facebook event is used on their infinite scroll, so that another script can be attached to the same event.

Comment: I do believe that there is a separated event to each type of loading, which kind do you want?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Currently having the same problem.

Comment: @greentea - No, unfortunately I ended up giving up on the idea. (I was trying to find it for a chrome extension)